# Distinguishing between external changes and application “controlled” changes in chokidar

Tags: node.js-fs, chokidar, fswatch

How can I distinguish between application-initiated changes and external changes when utilizing Chokidar to monitor file modifications in a specified directory?

I aim to trigger different actions based on these modification types. Currently, I'm employing a map with last-modified timestamps and using fs.Stats for comparison. However, this method feels cumbersome. Seeking a more efficient solution, specifically tailored to Chokidar.